# helm iterate over range

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can not find a way to iterate over a range in helm templating.
I have the next definition in my values.yaml:

```
ingress:
  app1:
    port: 80
    hosts:
      - example.com
  app2:
    port: 80
    hosts:
      - demo.example.com
      - test.example.com
      - stage.example.com
  app3:
    port: 80
    hosts:
      - app3.example.com
```

And i want to generate the same nginx ingress rule for each mentioned host with:

```
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.global.ingress }}
  - host: {{ $value.hosts }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /qapi
        backend:
          serviceName: api-server
          servicePort: 80
  {{- end }}
```

But it generates wrong hosts:

```
- host: [example.com]
- host: [test.example.com demo.example.com test.example.com]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've finally got it working using:

```
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.global.ingress }}
  {{- range $value.hosts }}
  - host: {{ . }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /qapi
        backend:
          serviceName: api-server
          servicePort: 80
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: Does anyone know why this requires a 'double iteration'?

Comment: @RobBell The first iterator iterates over the ingress keys, while the second iterator iterates over the hosts. The host ingress rule can only accept 1 host so you have to loop over all the possible hosts to generate a block for each one.